# Auto saving Outlook attachments VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I've been playing around with the below code in an attempt to save files which we receive daily in Outlook. The code seems to run fine, however, when I go to check the destination folder there are no attachments saved.

How can I modify the code to save the attachments to the specified folder?

```
 Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

    Private Sub Application_Startup()
        Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
        Set olApp = Outlook.Application
        Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
    End Sub

    Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

        'Only act if it's a MailItem
        Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem
        If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
            Set Msg = item

        'Change variables to match need. Comment or delete any part unnecessary.
            If (Msg.SenderName = "made-up-email@some_domain.com") And _
            (Msg.Subject = "Test") And _
            (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then

        'Set folder to save in.
        Dim olDestFldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim myAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
        Dim Att As String

        'location to save in.  Can be root drive or mapped network drive.
        Const attPath As String = "T:\London File3 Group\Client Reporting\Test"


        ' save attachment
           Set myAttachments = item.Attachments
        Att = myAttachments.item(1).DisplayName
        myAttachments.item(1).SaveAsFile attPath & Att

        ' mark as read
          Msg.UnRead = False
          End If
          End If
          End Sub
```

Comment: `attPath & Att` should be `attPath & "\" & Att`  If you comment out your error handling the problem should be clearer

Comment: I followed these instructions but the files are still not saving! What am I missing? There's no error as the code runs without any errors flagged without error handling.

Comment: Have you placed breakpoints and tried to debug your code to see which parts are actually executing?

Comment: No - I will try and do this now. I'm just confused that if there is no error then this implies the code has run fine?

Comment: "Run without errors" and "run as expected" aren't always the same thing ;-)

Comment: Acknowledged. Thanks for your help but still no luck identifying the issue :/

Comment: Does the `SaveAsFile` line actually execute?

Comment: Yes - very confusing

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code except what Tim already pointed out.  I'll add that you don't need to qualify your variables with the `Application` as the code is in Outlook - `Dim objNS As NameSpace` will work.  Would changing `Att = myAttachments.item(1).DisplayName` to `Att = myAttachments.item(1).FileName` work?

Comment: From my experience with this code I've found that `ItemAdd` doesn't fire when lots of emails are dumped in the folder - the [help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd) file says _This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once_, but it doesn't say what a large number is - my PC at works seems to think 3 is a large number.

Comment: With a little tweaking I managed to get it working for my inbox but now im trying to reference a subfolder within a shared mailbox. Anyone able to show the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work, something you may not have done is added this to the `ThisOutlookSession` object. Don't add to a standard module.

```
Private WithEvents InboxItems As Outlook.Items
Const attPath As String = "T:\London File3 Group\Client Reporting\Test\"

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application: Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace: Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set InboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub InboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim Msg             As Outlook.MailItem: Set Msg = Item
    Dim olDestFldr      As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myAttachments   As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim Filename        As String

    If Not TypeName(Msg) = "MailItem" Then Exit Sub
    If (Msg.SenderName = "made-up-email@some_domain.com") And (Msg.Subject = "Test") And (Msg.Attachments.Count >= 1) Then
        Set myAttachments = Item.Attachments
        Filename = myAttachments.Item(1).DisplayName
        myAttachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile attPath & Filename
        Msg.UnRead = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me... I used this code which again seems to run fine. However this time it saved a "thumbs.db" file in the specified folder. So it seems the script is running but not picking up the attachments. Any idea why?

Comment: Hi @Ryan Wildry. Managed to get this working, thanks V much. Do you know how I would reference a subfolder within a shared mailbox instead of my own inbox?

Comment: Hey Kyle, glad this helped. If it did, feel free to mark as the accepted answer. Feel free to raise a new question for help on getting the right folder. On StackOverflow, we like to limit the post to a single topic.